# iOS Contacts Framework - how to save/create new contact store

Tags: ios, swift, contacts

I'm looking to programatically create a new contact store and save contacts into it in Swift.

When trying to save a contact and using the `toContainerWithIdentifier:`, I have passed a string value to the container identifier however I am receiving the following error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error:
>   Error Domain=CNErrorDomain Code=200 "Updated Record Does Not Exist"
>   UserInfo={CNInvalidRecordIdentifiers=(
>       Local ), NSLocalizedDescription=Updated Record Does Not Exist, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The save request failed because it updates a
>   record that does not exist or has already been deleted.}

If I use this code `toContainerWithIdentifier:nil` the contact saves correctly in the default store, so I know there isn't an issue with my saving code.

It's a pretty basic test linked to a button. If I use anything else in `toContainerWithIdentifier` other than `nil` I get the error.

```
    @IBAction func testAdd(_ sender: UIButton) {
    contact.givenName = "John"
    contact.familyName = "Appleseed"
    let store = CNContactStore()
    let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest()
    saveRequest.add(contact, toContainerWithIdentifier:nil)
    try! store.execute(saveRequest)
}
```

Comment: can you please share the code that have been written to figure out the problem where would be.

Comment: Thanks have added.

Answer (score 1):

> create a new contact store

You can’t. The entire notion makes no sense. That’s why it’s failing. Any store you can save to must already exist. You should have no reason to use any identifier other than nil, the default store.

Comment: Thanks Matt for the response. I know with the Facebook app, when you used to be allowed to sync your contacts this would create it's own contact store and not use the default. Not sure why the notion makes no sense? I am looking to save them into a new contact store to ensure a consistent experience for the end users, rather than relying on Google, iCloud etc.

Comment: A contact store is a thing that lives online, except for the default which lives on the device (and can be mirrored online thru iCloud). Facebook could do that because it has online contact storage. You are not Facebook and have no online storage. — To put it another way, you (as a programmer) can save a contact into a contact store whose identifier you already have, because a contact came from there; but you can't just make one up out of your head. Do you see?

Comment: @depeter: It sounds like you wanted to create a new "container". That is different than the "store". in iOS the store points to the system/device's Contact's. Its basically a system service, but the docs don't say that. Thru that, you can access various containers (of accounts). See -> "Containers and Groups" "https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts, and "identifier" in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cnsaverequest/1403036-add